# List check constraints of Teradata table

Tags: constraints, teradata

I need to get list of all check constraints related to given table. For example, if there table

> create table table_with_check
>   ( S_BYTEINT BYTEINT NOT NULL,
>   CONSTRAINT CHECK_CONSTR CHECK(S_BYTEINT > 10)
>   )

I have only full table name and I need a query that returns me name of check constraint("CHECK_CONSTR") and its expression(S_BYTEINT > 10). The only thing I've found is system table DBC.ConstraintName but there only check constraint name but not expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no system table named `DBC.ConstraintName` in Teradata.

There's a view dbc.Table_LevelConstraintsV, based DBC.TableConstraints, which contains info about table level constraints like your `CHECK_CONSTR` and named constraints on column level. If you got an unnamed column constraint it's found in `dbc.ColumnsV.ColumnConstraint`.

Comment: I found check constraint expression in DBC.TableConstraints. Thank a lot for advice!